# jqtouch go back after form submiting

Tags: forms, jqtouch, back

I'm using jQtouch to build a page where the user can enter a kind of an ID and
get information (exam result) for this ID.
Because I take the results from the server, I used a form in the first page
with a text field and a submit button, and the action of this form send the user to the next page. Or at least, supposed to...

The problem is that also I'm being transferred to page with the results, and see the results properly, the Back button do nothing! BTW, in the address bar (above) I still see the name of the **first** page.

How can I go back to the "form" page? Thanks

```
<div class="current" id="byUserId">
<div class="toolbar">
<a class="back" id="goBack" > Back</a>
<h1> Exam Results</h1>
</div> ...
```

where the id="goBack" has a javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#goBack').click(function() {
        location.href = "enterId.jsp";
    });
});
```

Using the regular back doesn;t work either:

```
<a class="back" href="#"> Back</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I now this is pretty late, but I had a similar frustrations and finally figured it out. The problem is that jQTouch intercepts all AJAX and form submit commands and safely send them itself. This isn't a problem except for when it's expecting some sort of callback, and there isn't one. In my case, I wanted to submit a form without a callback. To do this, look in the `jqtouch.js` library (around line 434) and comment out the following line:

```
if (href != '#') {
   $.ajax({
      url: href,
      data: settings.data,
      type: settings.method,
      success: function (data) {
          **// var firstPage = insertPages(data, settings.animation);**
```

This basically just tells jQTouch to submit the AJAX call but do nothing afterwards (don't change div's, don't show any callbacks and don't do any animations). Hope this helps.